# Separate Assembly for each ASP.NET Server Control?

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls, project-organization

I started off creating a new project for each Server Control that I needed to create (for the purposes of flexibility and modularity). My latest project is a control that inherits TextBox in order to implement server-side enforcement of the MaxLength property, called SafeTextBox. So VS sets me up with my SafeTextBox project, with a class called ServerControl1 within the SafeTextBox namespace. Naturally I rename ServerControl1 to SafeTextBox. This creates the situation where, each time the class is referenced in code, I must type `SafeTextBox.SafeTextBox`.

Now that I have a few of these controls created, I am tempted to place them all into one assembly (CustomControls or similar), so that I could reference them as `CustomControls.SafeTextBox`, etc. Is there any reason that I should not do this? Is it possible to have multiple controls in one assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have multiple controls in one assembly?

YES, it is.

> Is there any reason that I should not do this?

You should have all the related controls in a single project to start with.

Your initial approach to have a separate project for each control is not easy to manage and maintain. Usually all the related GUI controls are placed in a single project. That makes them easily accessible via one reference and also one do not ends up with lots of dlls for your application.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I migrated the controls over into one assembly and already it's much easier to work with, especially across multiple projects/solutions.